# Sculpting won't change anything in blender

Tags: modeling, sculpting, error

For some reason whenever I'm in sculpting mode and use any brush, it doesn't do anything. Is it because I have it set too low to change anything in my settings? If so, could you show me a step by step process on how to fix it? Thanks. Also sorry for being unknowledgeable, I'm quite new to blender.

Comment: Are you trying to sculpt on the default cube? If you are, try adding more geometry by subdividing or turn on dynotopo with Ctrl+D when in sculpting mode. This will give a warning, just press ok. And try again.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple objects in your scene, make sure to select the mesh you want to sculpt on before switching to sculpt tab or sculpt mode.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it didn't work was because I didn't enable dynotopo, I was sculpting with an isosphere at around 6 arcs.